# unable to access data in view passed by controller Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I've tried to pass error message from controller to view if the login fails in Laravel 5.6 an error showing  in the view

> **Undefined variable $email_err**

Controller code,

```
        if($pass=="")
        {
            $email_err="Non Registred User";
            return view('login')->with('email_err ', $email_err);
        }
```

Controller name is **"LoginController"** and the Controller function is **"loginProcess"**

View Code,

```
{{ $email_err }}
```

View Form method is **"POST"**

Route,

```
Route::post('loginrequest', 'LoginController@loginProcess');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also pass the data as array. Since $email_err is a string you don't need to use foreach loop to access it

```
$email_err="Non Registred User";
return view('login',['email_err'=>$email_err]);
```

And in blade

```
{{$email_err}}
```

Comment: I've used /* return view('login')->with(['email_err'=>$email_err]); */ and it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

remove space in semicolon near `email_err`

```
return view('login')->with('email_err', $email_err);
```

Comment: Still no change

Comment: return View::make("login")->with('email_err',$email_err);

Comment: $data=array('email_err'=>$email_err);
View::make("login")->with($data);

Comment: How  to access the $data variable in view ? by using foreach() ?